# ServiceWorker 'fetch' event not triggered

Tags: service-worker

fetch event :

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

    console.log("[Service Worker] fetching "+event.request);

    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response) {
                    // Cache hit - return response
                    if (response) {
                        return response;
                    }
                    return fetch(event.request);
                }
            )
    );
});
```

Comment: You'll need to add more details, otherwise we can't help you. Do you have  a self.addEventListener('install', setup as well? Have you walked through:https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/? What are you seeing in the DevTools?

Comment: Other things to check: is your service worker scoped properly, and if you're testing before reloading the page, have you called `clients.claim()`? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#clientsclaim is useful.

Comment: hi @Aligned, i have install, activate and fetch event, so install and activate event fires in google chrome but fetch event does not fires. later on i checked with other browser in mozilla and Opera fetch event is working.